# Inverse Kronecker-Weber theorem

Tags: galois-theory

We all know about Kronecker-Weber theorem. But does the inverse hold?
What if some extension of $\mathbb Q$ is contained in a cyclotomic extension. Does it follow that the Galois Group of the extension is abelian?

Comment: Actually you don't know and are not prepared for the theorem when you don't immediately understand the easy direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call $E$ your cyclotomic extension, and $F$ your extension contained in $E$.

First of all, $F$ will be Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$, because $\operatorname{Gal}(E/\mathbb{Q})$ is abelian, and so its subgroup $\operatorname{Gal}(E/F)$ is normal.

And then $\operatorname{Gal}(F/\mathbb{Q})$ will be abelian, as the quotient of $\operatorname{Gal}(E/\mathbb{Q})$ over $\operatorname{Gal}(E/F)$.